# automatically resizing the menu bar by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I want to resize my navigation bar items, so there will be enough distance between them and the sticky logo. How can I achieve that? I tried to edit the container, but it didn't resize and instead overlapping appeared. I mean, it should be put to the right side and leave enough distance between the logo and the menu bar.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.testmonial {
    background-image: url(images/testimonial-bg.jpg);
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.testmonial:after {
    content: "";
    background: #1baaba;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .6;
    z-index: 1;
}

.owl-wrapper {
    padding: 80px 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}

.owl-testmonial {
    background: #FFF;
    /* max-width: 400px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 25px;
    position: unset;
}

.owl-testmonial:before {
    content: "\f10d";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 92px;
    color: #e7e7e7;
    margin-top: -106px;
}

.owl-testmonial .owl-prev {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 45%;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    border: 1px solid #FFF !important;
    width: 33px !important;
    height: 36px !important;
    line-height: 17px !important;
    color: #FFF;
}

.owl-testmonial .owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 45%;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    border: 1px solid #FFF !important;
    width: 33px !important;
    height: 36px !important;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 17px !important;
}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

nav.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li {
    margin: 0 30px;
}

nav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ffeb3b;
    color: black;
}

a.active {
    background-color: #2196f3;
    color: white;
}

.content {
    padding: 20px;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sticky ul {
    height: 50px;
    /* or any other desired height */
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sticky a {
    height: 100%;
    /* or any other desired height */
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.benefit-card,
.product,
.testimony,
.news-item,
.suggestion-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    float: left;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffeb3b;
    color: #2196f3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #2196f3;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.office-map {
    margin-top: 50px;
}


/* Responsive styles */

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    nav li {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    .benefit-card,
    .product,
    .testimony,
    .news-item,
    .suggestion-box {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
        height: 60vh;
    }
    nav {
        top: 60vh;
    }
    .benefit-card,
    .product,
    .testimony,
    .news-item,
    .suggestion-box {
        width: 90%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    header {
        height: 40vh;
    }
    nav {
        top: 40vh;
    }
    .benefit-card,
    .product,
    .testimony,
    .news-item,
    .suggestion-box {
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Add JS for owl carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>My Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="testmonial">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="owl-wrapper">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-testmonial">
                    <div class="slide-item">
                        <img src="testimony/slider1585663811.png" alt="Slide 1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-item">
                        <img src="testimony/slider1589942091.png" alt="Slide 2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-item">
                        <img src="testimony/slider1590030001.png" alt="Slide 3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 7 items sticky menu bar -->
    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul id="nav-ul">
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabungan">Tabungan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#kredit">Kredit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#deposito">Deposito</a></li>
            <li><a href="#berita">Berita</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pengajuan-kredit">Pengajuan Kredit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main class="content">
        <!-- 3 static benefits -->
        <section class="benefits">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Benefit 1</h3>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Benefit 2</h3>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Benefit 3</h3>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- 3 types of product -->
        <section class="products">
            <h2>Products</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Product 1</li>
                <li>Product 2</li>
                <li>Product 3</li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <!-- ID tracking -->
        <section class="id-tracking">
            <h2>ID Tracking</h2>
            <p>Description</p>
        </section>

        <!-- 3 dynamic testimonies -->
        <section class="testimonies">
            <h2>Testimonies</h2>
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="testimony-1">Testimony 1</div>
                <div class="testimony-2">Testimony 2</div>
                <div class="testimony-3">Testimony 3</div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- 4 dynamic slider of news -->
        <section class="news">
            <h2>News</h2>
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="news-1">News 1</div>
                <div class="news-2">News 2</div>
                <div class="news-3">News 3</div>
                <div class="news-4">News 4</div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- suggestion box -->
        <section class="suggestion-box">
            <h2>Suggestion Box</h2>
            <form action="#">
                <div>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="phone-number">Phone Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone-number" name="phone-number">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </section>

        <!-- static map to the office -->
        <section class="map">
            <h2>Map to the Office</h2>
            <img src="map.jpg" alt="Map to the Office">
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="owlcarousel/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="owlcarousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
        var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
        var logo = document.createElement("img");
        logo.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
        logo.style.height = "50px";
        logo.style.marginLeft = "40px";
        logo.style.float = "left";

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
                navbar.classList.add("sticky");
                if (!navbar.classList.contains("logo")) {
                    navbar.classList.add("logo");
                    navbar.insertBefore(logo, navbar.firstChild);
                    navbar.style.height = "50px";
                }
            } else {
                navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
                navbar.classList.remove("logo");
                navbar.removeChild(logo);
                navbar.style.height = "auto";
            }
        }

        window.onscroll = function() {
            myFunction();
        };
    </script>



</body>

</html>
```